# how to return returned value from another function without using return

Tags: php, oop

I want to check something in a function in PHP. I want to call a function in foo and if check passed nothing happen and if check dos not pass return something from foo function.

I now that can pass true|false from check function and use if statement into foo but I look for some easier solution,

```
public function foo($data) {

    AccessControll::CheckSpecificAccess();


    //resume computing
    return 'something';
}
```

---

```
class AccessControl {

    public static function CheckSpecificAccess() {
        //some computing ...

        if (!hasAccess)
            return 'you have not access';
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user has no access you can redirect him to an no acces page in your checkaccess function

Comment: What's the context? Where do you call foo from? is it a method into a controller? We need more info about the architecture to come with a better idea

Comment: This will get confusing very quickly. I would not recommend to do that. You call your method "CheckAccess" and a check can either be positive or negative. So returning true or false would be the right way to go. Call it "DenieAccess" and use redirect as Baracuda078 said if you want, but it is not good practice

Comment: @clash Can you explain me why its not a good practice? In my cms I also use a function like this. at the beginning of the controller I check his acl if that controller is not in his acl I redirect him to an no acces page. It keeps the controller clean

Comment: Or else you will have to write in every controller where you whant to check his permission the same if else statement

Comment: @MihaiMatei the foo function call in controller. but not normally.(--$class->$method()--). foo is a method in a class and I call that in controller. have some checks in construct but this check is exceptions

Comment: @Baracuda078 it is exactly my problem

Comment: @Baracuda078 A function that only returns a value "sometimes" should not be done. Type-Safety is more and more implemented into PHP, for a good reason. A function calling another function should always know what it can expect from it. A function that sometimes is void and sometimes returns a string is ok, but if this keeps on your code base will be unreadable at some point

Comment: Another point, to make code readable name your functions like what they do. CheckAccess should check if the user has access, nothing more. Redirecting should be done somewhere else. This of course is my opinion. You may want to read a little bit on clean code, I think it is a good thing to use some of there practices in order to know what your code does when you look at it in 2-3 months :)

Comment: @clash thank you for explain. but it's my fault in question. I do not want to return just a string. this function called in an Ajax request and I have a method for response standard json. I want to call that method with some errors code when has no access.

Comment: @clash I exactly did this. but did not mentioned in question.

Comment: @clash I agree with you to keep your code clean and readable, but like Mihai Matei said, we need a bit more on what function foo does. If it is a controller to render the view a check at the beginning and a redirect in the check is ok, but if it is a function in a function that is called in a function a redirect is indeed a bad idea

Comment: I think the access-check should not be in controller then, but before the controller is even called. That way you check access, return json with error if access it not granted and call controller if everything is ok. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: @clash maybe this logic was not  god idea. but I'm in middle of medium project and can't change all logic. 
there is many roles and access in project that handle with DB and controllers.
this problem happen when some condition like this: i want to update my comment in a post and send request with details and comment primary key.
server should check if user has access to this specific comment actions updates and if not access response access denied. 
bigger access checks done in controller

Comment: Hmm I am a little lost. The last thing I can think of to make this work is to output everything in CheckAccess and then exit out of the program.

Comment: @clash thank you for your response very much. I decided to check these access  checks in higher layers controllers.